# CKEditor dont wrap Tags like Iframe with P

Tags: javascript, iframe, ckeditor

My ***ckeditor*** is on `EnterMode` P Tag which is right. But when I add an Iframe to it. It also wraps the iframe with a P Tag. I tried then to set `autoParagraph` to `false` but then he also don`t wrap Text content with P tags when its inserted over the source code. The content manager mostly paste their text over the source code to get ride of the styling and then the P Tag is missing. How I can set the iframe tag to be used as a main tag it works for div tags but not for iframes they are wrapped always with a P tag autoParagraph I cant turn of because of the text content.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell ckeditor to treat `iframe` as an inline element, like `span`.

Edit `plugin.js` located under `ckeditor/plugins/iframe/`. In the `init` function add `CKEDITOR.dtd.$inline['iframe'] = 1;` so the code looke like this:

```
init: function (editor) {
    CKEDITOR.dtd.$inline['iframe'] = 1;
    var pluginName = 'iframe',
```

Be aware that after applying this change your iframes will be added inline, so if you need them to start on a new paragraph you will have to hit Enter before.